# How can I change an attribute value for all list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple structure like:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="costsDropdown">
    <li data-position="bla bla"></li>
</ul>
```

and I want to change each "data-position" attribute of my list Elements.

My first **Jquery** Shot was this here:

```
$("#costsDropdown ul").each(function() {
    $("li").attr("data-position", "TEST-VALUE123");
});
```

but it doesnt work, I think my selector are wrong...

could anyone give me a hint please?

Thanks for any help!

Greetz

Comment: `$("#costsDropdown ul")` matches nothing, it has to be `$("#costsDropdown")` (`#costsDropdown` ***is*** the `ul`). And even that is unnecessary. Go `$("li[data-position]").attr("data-position", "TEST-VALUE123");`

Comment: Well, first of all inside your loop will be trying to access all <li>'s on your page, not just bound to your parent selector.

Comment: $("#costsDropdown ul") return all <ul> under the DOM ID "costsDropdown", just use $("#costsDropdown li"). Then use this instead of $("li")

Comment: @connexo, sorry but your code line did not work :(

Comment: @Aks Hey Aks, also this here: $("#costsDropdown li").attr("data-position", "TEST-VALUE123"); works fine thanks for your help man ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your selectors are a bit off

```
$("#costsDropdown ul").each
```

That is trying to select the child `ul` of the container `#costsDropdown` (which is the ID of the `ul`) - what you want is:

```
$("#costsDropdown li").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-position", "TEST-VALUE123");
});
```

ID's are unique - no need to double up the selector with an ID *and* the type of element it is.

Note that I used `$(this)`, not `$("li")`, inside the `each` callback. `$("li")` selects **all** `li` elements, anywhere on the page; we just want a jQuery wrapper for the one specific one we're handling inside the `each`.

In fact, the `each` is completely unnecessary because of the set-based nature of jQuery; if you use the `.attr` setter, it sets the attribute on all elements in the set:

```
$("#costsDropdown li").attr("data-position", "TEST-VALUE123");
```

That will set the value on **all** of the `li` elements inside `#costsDropdown`.

If you need to set separate individual values on the individual `li` elements, you still don't need `each` (though it's fine if you want to use it); you can use the version of `attr` that accepts a callback that it uses to find out what value to set:

```
$("#costsDropdown li").attr("data-position", function(index) {
    return "Test value " + index;
});
```

That will set `"Test value 0"` on the first `li`, `"Test value 1"` on the second, etc. And like the `each` example above, if you need to, you can use `this` within the callback to refer to the `li` for that call (possibly using `$(this)` to wrap it if you need a jQuery wrapper).

Comment: this also works great! Thanks! i will mark this answer in 2 min. :p and thx for your explanation

Comment: @nbg15: See the update above for more information. Good answer from tymeJV (no surprise there).

Answer (score 0):

`$("#costsDropdown ul")` matches no elements, it has to be `$("#costsDropdown")` (`#costsDropdown` ***is*** the `ul`).

And even that is unnecessary. Go

`$("li[data-position]").attr("data-position", "TEST-VALUE123");`

instead.